# how to Modifying data to make it unique?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table that has  3000 email addresses but they are not unique, I want to make them unique by somehow modifying them like adding number before @ symbol.
I want to use this for just testing, modifying data is fine in my case.

I have fields like f_name,l_name,email_id,ph_number,Address,city,state etc. I just want to modify email_id to make it unique. Any thoughts on how to do it in oracle is greatly appreciated? Thanks!

Comment: What would you do with random email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rownum` psudocolumn to modify the values, as Vikas Harida hinted at:

```
update t
set email_id = substr(email_id, 1, instr(email, '@') - 1)
  || rownum || substr(email_id, instr(email, '@'));
```

The existing `email_id` is split at the `@`, then put back together with the `rownum` in the middle.

For example:

```
create table t (email_id varchar2(80));

table T created.

insert into t (email_id)
select 'someone@gmail.com' from dual
union all select 'someone@gmail.com' from dual
union all select 'someone@gmail.com' from dual
union all select 'someone@yahoo.com' from dual
union all select 'someone@yahoo.com' from dual;

5 rows inserted.

update t
set email_id = substr(email_id, 1, instr(email_id, '@') - 1)
  || rownum || substr(email_id, instr(email_id, '@'));

5 rows updated.

select * from t;

EMAIL_ID                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
someone1@gmail.com                                                               
someone2@gmail.com                                                               
someone3@gmail.com                                                               
someone4@yahoo.com                                                               
someone5@yahoo.com
```

If you want something a bit more uniform (though I don't think you care), and you have access to the `dbms_random` package, you can do:

```
update t
set email_id = substr(email_id, 1, instr(email_id, '@') - 1)
  || trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 9999))
  || substr(email_id, instr(email_id, '@'));
```

... which gives something like:

```
EMAIL_ID                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
someone6584@gmail.com                                                            
someone988@gmail.com                                                             
someone9837@gmail.com                                                            
someone4026@yahoo.com                                                            
someone6365@yahoo.com
```

But you could potentially get collisions - the same 'random' number assigned twice in the same run - which can't happen with `rownum`.

Either way, adding characters to an existing value could make it too long for the column, so you'll need to watch out for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add row numbers to email Id so it will automatically became unique.

Comment: how do I do that? can you provide an example please?